# A one ton Chevy pick up no reverse

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, silverado

2000 Chevy Silverado one ton truck. This truck has an automatic transmission 4L-80 E   My son was using it to back and forth to school then one day no reverse

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How many miles on the truck?

Comment: Linkage out of adjustment? Checked the fluid level?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bad vehicle speed sensor on the transmission. If the control module senses a speed reference greater than 8 mph during the shift into reverse, it has the ability to prevent the shift from happening.   Try disconnecting and see if you have reverse.

Otherwise probably will require a pressure test by a transmission shop to diagnose.